# pg_dump with dbname - invalid port number?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

When using the `dbname` parameter with `pg_dump.exe`, I get the following error:

**Error:**

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "my_database" failed:
>   invalid port number:
>   "mypass@my_server.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/my_database"

**Command:**

```
pg_dump.exe --dbname=postgresql://my_user@my_server:mypass@my_server.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/my_database
```

I assume this is due to the '@' in the username. But without providing the server/host, I get this:

> pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "my_database" failed: FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the
>       Username and retry connection. The Username should be in  format.
>       FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in  format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try connection string (with urlencoded value instead `@`), eg:

```
t=# create user "us@r" password 'a@a';
CREATE ROLE
t=# grant CONNECT ON DATABASE t TO "us@r";
GRANT
t=# grant all on a to "us@r";
GRANT
t=# \! pg_dump -d "postgres://us%40r:a%40a@localhost:5432/t" -t a -s | head -n 3
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--
```